# Is there a Method to move a button in the Legacy GridLayout?

Tags: java, android

I need to switch the position of a button for example from row 0 column 0 to row 1 column 1 in the Legacy GridLayout. Is there any Method in Java for that?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grdlyt"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="2">


<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_f1_a1"
        android:layout_width="202dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:onClick="f1a1Clicked"
        android:text="Affalterbach"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0" />
```

The Design looks like this:

[image: The Design]

And the Start of the XML looks like this:

[image: Start of XML]

Comment: Downvote for not reading the [android-studio] tag usage guidance.

Comment: Upvote because the OP is a new user and had no way of necessarily knowing.

Comment: Hello Pereki, welcome to SO. You'd need to provide slightly more information to be helped with this; in essence, it's hard to tell what kind of "grid" you're talking about; is this a RecyclerView using a GridLayoutManager? Can you post some code of how you populate said "grid" ? Stuff like that gives you more chances anyone can help you, otherwise, it's impossible to tell what is going on.

Comment: I used the Legacy GridLayout. There isnt really JavaCode in this project but i can send you the XML. The XML-Snippet is now in the Question.

Comment: I haven't used the GridLayout since maybe 2012? so I cannot help you with that; however, you seem to have ConstraintLayout as your root (hint given by `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` kind of thing) is this the case? If so, post your entire XML and a sshot of how you want it to look and maybe we can help you better :)

Comment: Thank you really much for your help! Yep i have a ConstraintLayout as root.